# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi} \log(2+\cos x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried integrating it by part but it didn't work. I konw it can be solved by the [Gauss Mean Value theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504969/how-to-prove-lim-n-to-infty-prod-i-0n-1-2-cos-fraci-pin?noredirect=1#comment1083857_504969) .Is there some elementary method for evaluate it or just some others? It seems there are at least [four differential ways](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/f9d44557e45c3b3567ec8bdc.html)(page 4 (17)) but I cannot think out any(the link only says there are four but not give any way).

Comment: Related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114401/a-problem-about-parametric-integral).

Comment: @user37238 I wish I see your comment before wasting time in composing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what counts as elementary. One way is to consider 
\begin{align}I(a)&=\int_0^{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{a+a^{-1}}{2}+\cos x\right)dx=\\
&=
\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{a+a^{-1}}{2}+\cos x\right)dx=\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\left[-\ln 2a+\ln\left(1+ae^{ix}\right)+\ln\left(1+ae^{-ix}\right)\right]dx.
\end{align}
with $0<a<1$. The integrals of $\ln\left(1+ae^{\pm ix}\right)$ are equal to zero. To show this, just expand the logarithms in Taylor series in $a$ and integrate termwise. Therefore,
$$I(a)=-\pi\ln 2 a.$$
In your case, $a+a^{-1}=4$ so that $a=2-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Great ! How does the ideal of using $I(a)$ or $ln（\frac{a+a^{-1}}{2}+cosx)$ come out?

Comment: @frame99 Essentially, the aim is to write $\alpha+\cos x$ as $\beta (1+ \gamma e^{i x}) (1+ \delta e^{-i x})$ with some $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ (with $|\gamma|, |\delta| <1$). Writing $2\alpha=a+a^{-1}$ is just a convenient parameterization of these coefficients (note that for $e^{\pm ix}= -a$ the expression $\alpha+\cos x$ vanishes).

Comment: As it is a trigonometry form. Is it a natural way to think the Euler formula?

Comment: @frame99 The exponentials are in most cases better than the sines and cosines. But if you find this derivation not-intuitive, there many others. For example, you can consider instead of $\ln(2+\cos x)$ a more general function $\ln(2+t \cos x)$. Then differentiating the integral with respect to parameter $t$ you will get rid of the logarithm and will be able to compute the antiderivative. Then integrate back the result with respect to $t$. This is very similar in the spirit to the answer of **achille hui**.

Answer (score 4):

Another way: **differentiate under integral sign**!

Let $\displaystyle\quad J(a) = \int_0^\pi \log(a + \cos x) dx,\quad$ and $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
J'(a) 
= & \int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{a + \cos x} 
= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac{2 dt}{1+t^2}}{a + \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}
= \frac{2}{a+1}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1 + \frac{a-1}{a+1}t^2}\\
= & \frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{1+s^2} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}
\end{align}$$
Let $a = \cosh\theta$, and integrate over $a$, we get

$$\begin{align}
F(a) 
= & \int F'(a) da = \pi \int \frac{d\cosh\theta}{\sqrt{\cosh^2\theta-1}}\\
= & \pi \theta + C  = \pi\cosh^{-1}(a) + C = \pi \log( a + \sqrt{a^2 - 1} ) + C\tag{*1}
\end{align}$$
for some integration constant $C$. For large $a$, we have

$$\log(a + \cos x) = \log a + \frac{\cos x}{a} + O(\frac{1}{a^2})
\quad\implies\quad 
J(a) = \pi \log a + O(\frac{1}{a})\tag{*2}
$$
Compare $(*1)$ with $(*2)$, we find $C = -\pi \log 2$ and hence:

$$J(a) = \pi\log\left(\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2-1}}{2}\right)$$

In particular, the integral we want to calculate is $\displaystyle\quad J(2) = \pi\log\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$.